# How to change native-base Picker fontSize and fontFamily in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have a Picker in my component. Is there any way to set `fontSize` and `fontFamily`?

I tried:

```
style={{fontFamily:'iransans',fontSize:14}}
```

and

```
itemTextStyle={{fontFamily:'iransans',fontSize:14}}
```

but neither of them worked for me.

```
<Picker
note
mode="dropdown"
style={{fontFamily:'iransans',fontSize:14 }}
itemTextStyle={{fontSize:16}} ...
```

Answer (score -1):

`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                
                <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
                <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
        </style>

        <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arab_font</item>

        </style>
        <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

        


        </style>
```

`

Comment: Please read "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.